# Mocking Database for API Test

Tags: c#, api, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking

I'm new to C# and .Net and trying to get into Unit Testing my API.
I created a project consisting of an actual Database, a controller for data access, a business layer and a REST-API.

I need some kind of test database to test my POST- and my GET-Methods.
And I would like to initialize this test database with some test data for the GET-Methods.

I already tried to solve the problem following a Microsoft tutorial about mocking databases, but the test database is interfering with my actual database constructor in the controller and the tutorial only works with a mocked database.

Here is my controller with its DB constructor

```
namespace TSM_Programm.Controllers
{
    public class ItemController : ControllerBase
    {

        //Constructor for DB usage 
        private TSMContext _context;

        public ItemController(TSMContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // Get all items
        public List<Item> Getitems()
        {

            return _context.items.ToList();
        }

       //and so on...
```

And in my API those controller methods get called with the typical Http features and a business layer constructor

```
    [ApiController]
    public class APIController : Controller
    {

        private readonly BusinessController _business;

        public UserController(BusinessController business)
        {
            _business = business;
        }

        //GET Itemlist
        [HttpGet("AllItems")]
        public List<Item> GetAllItems()

        {
           return List<Item> newlist = _business.GetAllItems().ToList();

        }
```

I already created a second database class which is a interface, but i do not know how to put it in my controller, so i can use it for unit testing.

for reference:

```
namespace TSM_Programm.Data
{
    public interface ITestDatabase : IDisposable
    {

        DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }     
        DbSet<MoreItem> MoreItems { get; set; }
        DbSet<SomeMoreItem> SomeMoreItems{ get; set; }

        int SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

And my actual DB class

```
namespace TSM_Programm.Data
{
    public class TSMContext : DbContext, ITestDatabase
    {

        public TSMContext(DbContextOptions<TSMContext> options) : base(options){ }
        
        DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }     
        DbSet<MoreItem> MoreItems { get; set; }
        DbSet<SomeMoreItem> SomeMoreItems{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Can you give me a hint what I'm doing wrong?
Are there any tutorials that fit my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of injection Db Context into your api controller you should inject a repository then in your unit test you mock the repository.

you also should not be injecting a controller into another controller.

your decency graph should look somewhat like this.

apicontroller -> Repo -> DbContext

or

apicontroller -> service -> Repos -> DbContext

[Here is an Example on how to test a controller on Microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Ok, I tried to get into this, but I do not know how to prevent controller injection, when I need to use the methods from my business controller in my API controller and how to make sure the API uses the test database for tests and the real database for its actual task.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with the ITestDatabase is really not required and can be removed if the purpose of its creation is for testing purposes.
Instead what you can do you is, create a second database purely for testing purposes. It can be called as the TestDb and loaded with test data.

Once that is in place, in order to test your methods in controller, use a testing framework like xunit to write your tests which mimic the behavior of calling the get and post methods and execute them by connecting to the test database.

The inline link can serve as a starting point to setup your tests.

[Unit Testing web api with x unit](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operations-unit-testing-in-asp-net-core-web-api-with-xunit/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, I created a testdatabase, alongside my real database, and seeded it with some test data so i can use it for comparison in my assert-part of the test. How can I make sure my data access layer connects to the testdatabase and not the real one during testing?

Comment: you need to use a different connection string inside of your tests project while creating the database context object to connect to test database.